# How to implement PHP inside a image src code?

Tags: php, html, image, src

```
    <img src="socimages/logo/"<?php if ($soca == ""){ echo "logo.jpg"; } else { echo $anotherimage . ".jpg";} ?>>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to change the end part of the image `src`, to pick from a range of specifically named images.

The syntax for the code is obviously not right since I closed the `src` after `/logo/` with the `"`. But if I do not have the " then my php will not function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [ternary](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/), and remember to distinct between `""` and `''` :

```
<img src="socimages/logo/<? echo $soca == '' ? 'logo.jpg' : $anotherimage . '.jpg'; ?>">
```

This will produce a correct `<img src="image.jpg">` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, don't mess the logic in your `img` tag.

```
<?php
    $img = ($soca == "") ? "logo.jpg" : $anotherimage.".jpg";
?>

<img src="socimages/logo/<?php echo $img; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A ternary conditional makes the line shorter:

```
<img src="socimages/logo/<?php echo ($soca=='')?'logo.jpg':$anotherimage.'.jpg';?>">
```

This is probably shortest:

```
<img src="socimages/logo/<?php echo ($soca=='')?'logo':$anotherimage;?>.jpg">
```

Or even this variant, but it depends on the short tags configuration of your site:

```
<img src="socimages/logo/<?= ($soca=='')?'logo':$anotherimage;?>.jpg">
```

But all variants are *horrible* style. You should always try to implement in a *transparent* manner, easy to read and understand. So instead store the final path inside a variable and echo that into the src attribute of the img tag.